# calculator numbers Equation

Tags: jquery, calculator

i creat a calculator and i want to show the Equation on the "result" screen

for example: 22+30

at this moment the "plus" sign just dissapear

```
$('#plus').on('click', function () {
      plus += parseInt($('#result').html());
      $('#result').html('');   
});
```

here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/zJLJp/9/

Comment: Your plus sign doesn't disappear for me.

Comment: You must have fixed your issue. The calculator is working much better now.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zJLJp/11/

Comment: @pasta12 nope it still don't write the equation on the result screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  `$('#result').html($('#result').html()+'+');` instead of `$('#result').html('');`

```
$('#plus').on('click', function () {
      plus += parseInt($('#result').html());
      $('#result').html($('#result').html()+'+');   
});

$('#equal').on('click', function () {
   // var equal = plus + parseInt($('#result').html());
    var total = 0;
    var exp = $('#result').html();
    exp = exp.match(/[+]*(\.\d+|\d+(\.\d+)?)/g) || [];
    while(exp.length){
        total+= parseFloat(exp.shift());
    }
    $('#result').html(total);
    plus = 0;
});
```

**NOTE:** No need to use plus variable anymore (until and unless if you are planning to add other operators).

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zJLJp/14/)**</kbd>

Comment: i feel like it's close to the sulotion but if u try it u see that the result get wierd

Comment: ok thank you very much! really helped me, one thing, why when i do somthing like 10+010 = 18? and sp on?

Comment: Numbers preceded by a zero is interpreted as octal, that's why it equals 18.

Comment: Oh, and eval is evil.

Comment: @alonblack - did you even notice the fiddle I posted 15 minutes ago ?

Comment: @Unknown thank you very much for your help this works perfect now. can u pleas try to explain to me the code?

Comment: @alonblack `/[+]*(\.\d+|\d+(\.\d+)?)/g` regex to get expression with comma separated values then we will check the length and add those numbers `.shift()` will remove values from array one by one.

Comment: @Unknown ok thanks for ur time!! by the way is it ok that on click '+' can show +++++++?

Comment: @alonblack No its not good to add n number of +. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/zJLJp/15/